# DebuggerDisplay command says a closing bracket is missing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am trying to add a DebuggerDisplay to a class, and am getting an error. The class looks like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Site = {SiteName}")]
Public Class SiteContact
    Inherits BusinessBase
    Implements IBusiness
```

I am getting an error stating that the Bracketed identifier is missing a closing ']'. The closing bracket is obviously there, and when I look at the suggested solutions, it wants to place the bracket after DebuggerDisplay. If I follow this, I get an error that a declaration was expected.

I've tried copying the code from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and it gives me the same error. I am working in Visual Studio 2010, and using VB .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used the C# attribute formatting - in VB it should be:

```
<DebuggerDisplay("Site = {SiteName}")>
Public Class SiteContact
    Inherits BusinessBase
    Implements IBusiness
```

Comment: That was it. I'm not sure why all the sites suggested the square brackets [] unless this is what is used for c#, and <> is used for VB. When searching for the command I did use VB. Anyway, I will mark this as the answer when SO allows me to. Thank you.

Comment: Info: Older VB versions not having the automatic line continuation feature require you to add a "_" after the attribute or to place it on the same line as the class.